# what is the word that describes someone who keeps their real personality secret?

Tags: word-choice

I knew a word for this a while ago. It sounded French or Italian and may have begun with im or em or something. It basically describes somebody who gives off one type of personality and keeps their own secret or I guess just someone who keeps their own personality secret. Anyone know what I'm talking about?

Comment: An [impostor](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impostor)?

Comment: Someone with a *dual personality* or a *double life*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*Incognito*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/incognito), via Italian from Latin *incognitus*, quite literally "unknown".

> *adjective*
>   Without being known; in disguise; in an assumed character, or under an assumed title.
>
> *adverb*
>   Without revealing one's identity.
>
> *noun*
>
> 1. One unknown or in disguise, or under an assumed character or name.
> 2. The assumption of disguise or of a feigned character; the state of being in disguise or not recognized.

Comment: Though incognito can be applied to both sexes in English, sometimes **incognita** is used for women also.

Comment: I can appreciate its use as an adverb. You can arrive incognito, appear incognito, present yourself incognito, or act incognito (among others). Adjectivally I suppose you could refer to an incognito guest at a party. But how would you use incognito, in relation to personality? Can you give an example of a sentence?